# Jquery Slideup Function shows a bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using the slideUp function to slideup and down an adblock message, but when  you see the adblock alert, after you scroll down, it takes a second for the navigation bar to adjust to the top. It gives the whole process a buggy look--this change should be instant and perfect.

you can see an example here: https://www.mallyear.com/search?q=phone

the code Im using for the slideUp function is this:

```
jQuery(window).on("scroll", function(){


   //  adblocker is the Id for the ad message
   // t3-header is the Id for the Nav bar

    var startY = 1; 

    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > startY){

        jQuery('#adblocker').slideUp("fast");
          jQuery('#t3-header').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});



    }else{

        jQuery('#adblocker').slideDown("fast");
        jQuery('#t3-header').css({position: 'static', top: '80px'});

    }

        });
```

To see this adblock notification, is needed an extension like "Ad Blocker Plus" on Google Chrome, and you should have it running. The bug shows when scrolling down just for a second but is there. Many thanks for the help

Comment: On a side note, you just need to change the position to static, the top value does not need to change and is not applied when an element is static

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure that this is what you're looking for, but I imagine you want to have the css for t3-header be changed only after the slide has completed, right?

If so, anything you want to happen once the slide is finished should be in a function passed as an additional argument to the slideUp/slideDown function. For example:

```
jQuery('#adblocker').slideUp("fast", function() {
    jQuery('#t3-header').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
});
```

If that's not the cause of the problem my apologies!

**EDIT**

After the comments I wonder if maybe you should cut out the slideUp animation all together, and just have the navBar stay fixed to the top once the user has scrolled beyond the adblock div (150px as I understand it). I would change the code to this:

```
if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 150){
    jQuery('#t3-header').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
}else{
    jQuery('#t3-header').css({position: 'static'});
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Ok one more option, but this would require changing how your elements are set up.

The problem with having the ad-blocker slide up is that by definition the user will already have scrolled down a bit, so by the time the ad-blocker div has fully slid up, the navbar will have already gone over scroll-top, only to snap back down again once its css has been changed to fixed.

So what you need is to have both the navbar and the adblocker div be in one fixed, container div. This will nullify the need to change the css of the navbar itself, and you can use the slideUp animation on adblocker with it ending in the correct place. So you have:

```
<div id ="navContainer" style="position:fixed; top:0px">
    <div id = "adblocker" class = "container-fluid">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id = "t3-header" class="container t3-header">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

(you could put that css in your css file once you're happy with what you have of course)

And in javascript you have:

```
if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 1){
    jQuery('#adblocker').slideUp("fast")
}else{
    jQuery('#adblocker').slideDown("fast")
}
```

I suspect that will provide the effect you're hoping for.

Comment: I think the OP wants the opposite

Comment: thanks you but is not fixing the bug which is that on the slideup the nav bar won't adjust fast enough and it looks bad

Comment: Do you want the navbar to rise naturally with the scrolling of the window, or to rise at the same speed as the slideUp animation? My answer supposes the second option. The problem is that your code as it is now sets the navbar to the top position at the same time as starting the slideUp animation, making the animation unnecessary. I would add that having the navbar just rise with scrolling would look more natural in my opinion

Comment: @MichaelBeeson How can achieve this?

Comment: @MichaelBeeson code works ok but it looks forced not sliding up the navbar

Comment: @ClaudioMartinez Ok I think I know what you're looking for. I've provided one more possible solution on my answer